# Why is my one form submitting both the forms on this page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have two forms that I want to be submitted from new.html.erb, which is served by status_updates Controller. The init form, and the the stat form.

When I submit the stat form, everything works  perfectly.

The init form has a different controller it answers to. The problem is that when I submit this form it immediately tries to find the object for the *stat* form within the controller for the init form.

If I go to that controller and provide the an instance of the object, it'll submit *both* forms.

Here's the error when I submit the init form.

```
undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class
 <div id='stat'>
   <%= form_for(@status_update) do |f| %>
```

The stat form submits fine. When the init form is submitted it tries to process the stat form as well. If I provide the model @status_update within init's  action controller it will submit both forms. If not, it throws the above error.

Here's the code for init form

```
<div id='init'>
  <%= form_for(current_user, method: :put ) do |f| %>

    <%= f.label :target_bf_percent %>
    <%= f.text_field :target_bf_pct %>

    <%= f.label :Deficit_percent %>
    <%= f.text_field :deficit_pct %>

    <%= f.label :activity_factor %>
    <%= f.select( :activity_factor, options_for_select( 
                                [['Pick One', nil],
                                ['Sedentary (Desk Job)', 1.2],
                                ['Light Activity (1-3 day a week)', 1.35],
                                ['Moderate Activity (3-5 days a week)', 1.55],
                                ['Very Active ( 6-7 days a week)', 1.75],
                                ['Extremely Active (Atheletic Endurance)', 1.95]]) )
    %>
  <%= f.submit "Post", class:"btn btn-large btn-primary" %> 
<% end %>

</div>
```

And the code for the stat form

```
<div id='stat'>
  <%= form_for(@status_update) do |f| %>

    <%= f.label :current_weight %>
    <%= f.text_field :current_weight %>

    <%= f.label :current_bf_pct %>
    <%= f.text_field :current_bf_pct %>

    <%= f.submit "Post", class:"btn btn-large btn-primary" %> 
 <% end %>
```

The status_update controller new action:

```
def new
  @status_update = current_user.status_update.build if user_signed_in?
end
```

The users controller update action:

```
def update
    if current_user.update_attributes!(params[:user])
      flash[:success] = "Your personal settings have been saved!"
      render new_status_update_path
    else
      flash[:error] = "Whoops! There was an error saving your personal settings. Please try again."
      render new_status_update_path
    end
 end
```

---

- Please let me know of anything I can do to improve this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't matter if you render one or more forms on the same page.

Your problem is caused by @status_update because it is nil, but you already know that.

Double check if it is initialized in your controller.

Comment: I will check. Although, how come if I don't include one or the other and submit the form it goes through correctly?

Comment: My controller has this in it:   def new
      @status_update = current_user.status_update.build if user_signed_in?
  end

Comment: Forms don't conflict each other, it's just that you can submit only one at a time. So yes, it has to work.

Comment: Hmm.. it should be signed in.

Comment: There params say this..."controller"=>"users"... which is the controller for the other form.

Comment: Yes, but it's a bad design. If your user is not signed in, you should redirect him to sign in. Your new action is bugged. Add a new line like this : raise "Not signed in!" unless user_sign_in?

Comment: Well, each form is handled by a different controller. It looks like when I submit one form it tries to process the other form as though it were part of the first forms controller. theres a users_controller and status_update_controller

Comment: So I think I have to specify which controller to look at for the other form.

Comment: Yes, the user is definitely signed in. I've set it up so that you can't access these pages unless the user is signed in.